# How to code against the navigation area next to the site actions

Tags: development, custom

I'm trying to create a custom navigation area. Is there a way to get a custom coded control/web part, ect in this area?  Any advice would be greatly appreciated. I'm trying to get a "most visited" section added to this nav area.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Requires you to extend the SharePoint PopoutMenu and provide your own sitemapprovider which contains the given parameter to use the provided details.